# Best Practice for Headers/Footer/Reusable Templates in Node.JS/Express Views?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, templates, middleware

I have my development environment set up with Node.JS / Express / Pug and I'm learning how to use views & routes, but I can't find a definitive answer on how to include a "reusable" nav bar and footer.

In PHP you just include your header.php and footer.php files and it pulls them in to every page, what is the best way to do this in Node/Express?

I see the term "partial view" being thrown around but not in relation to headers and footers, so I'm looking for the best way to achieve this.

Say I have 3 views: index, about, & contact how would I include the same nav bar & footer in all 3 of these without copying and pasting it into each view?  Just need a good push in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html

Comment: @JonasW. Oh. I was over complicating this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compose responses youve got a few options:

1) Let the template engine do its job:

```
  doctype html
  html
    include includes/head.pug
```

doc

2) use express to send multiple files at once:

```
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const header = fs.createReadStream("header.html");
    header.pipe(res);
    header.on("close", next);
  });

  app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    // Send the homepage
  });

  //....
```